# Applying Office2007 theme on RibbonBar on WPF

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, ribbon

I downloaded Microsoft Ribbon for WPF.
I installed it, and as expected, it **is** Awesome.

But when I'm trying to change the theme with the following code, VS claims that he cannot find the file.

```
<ribbon:RibbonWindow.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/RibbonControlsLibrary;component/Themes/Office2007Black.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ribbon:RibbonWindow.Resources>

Error   1   An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "/RibbonControlsLibrary;component/Themes/Office2007Black.xaml". C:\Users\Gilad\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GameofLife\MainWindow.xaml  11  17  GameofLife
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither Office2007Blue.xaml nor Office2007Black.xaml get shipped with the Ribbon control anymore, if you want to change its style you have to write your own style.